# Passing 2D array into function

Tags: c++, arrays

I'd like to pass my 2D Array of class Menza into function..

```
class Menza
{
    public:
    string PrintLunch() const {return Lunch;};
    unsigned int PrintID() const {return ID;};
    double PrintPrice() const {return Price;};
    double PrinteValue() const {return eValue;};
    string PrintDescription() const {return Description;};
    void ChangeLunch(string Change) {Lunch = Change;};
    void ChangePrice(double Change) {Price = Change;};
    void ChangeID(int Change) {ID = Change;};
    void ChangeeValue(double Change) {eValue = Change;};
    void ChangeDescription(string Change) {Description = Change;};
private:
    string Lunch;
    double Price;
    unsigned int ID;
    string Description;
    double eValue;
};

const int Lunches = 5;

void LoadFile(bool FileChoice,Menza (*InputFromFile)[Lunches]);
void CustomerSelection(Menza CustomerSelect[],Menza (*InputFromFile)[Lunches]);

int main()
{
    Menza InputFromFile[Lunches][Lunches];
    Menza CustomerSelect[Lunches];
    bool FileChoice = false;

    LoadFile(FileChoice,InputFromFile);
    CustomerSelection(CustomerSelect,InputFromFile);
}
```

Once I compile this, it shows me:

```
Semestralka.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl LoadFile(bool,class Menza (*)[5])" (?LoadFile@@YAX_NPAY04VMenza@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>E:\My VSB\ZP projekty\Semestralka\Debug\Semestralka.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Can someone explain me whats wrong in this function call?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the definition of `LoadFile`?

Comment: Under the declaration of: const int Lunches = 5;

Comment: That's a declaration. Where is the definition?

Comment: void InputFile(bool FileChoice,Menza (*InputFromFile)[Lunches])
{
 // some stuff
}

Comment: Is this being linked in Semestralka.exe? Is the value of "Lunches" the same in both cases? If your problem is resolved by moving the definition so it's right above `main`, then the answer to one of those questions is probably "no".

Answer (score 0):

You don't have definition of `LoadFile` function, only declaration. Therefore compiler have no way to understand what this function should do. 
You must define it or link a library where it is defined (and include a header from this library). (Same is true for `CustomerSelection` too).

Read more about difference between definition and declaration here: [declare_vs_define](http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4uiGNEbw

Theres my full code(its not finished yet), Declarations and also Definitions of my methods are there too.. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: @user3072249, be more specific please. Where do you have definition of LoadFile(...)?  I do not see it there.